Audio with Jack and PipeWire Latency Adjustment
I use Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS, with PipeWire, Jack and PulseAudio.
Before the upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04, we could adjust the audio latency with qjackctl app. But, from the arise of PipeWire... OMG!!!
Now, I just get the following panel from qjackctl:

Before the PipeWire arise, we could set the "Frames/Period" and "Period/Buffer" boxes as we wanted. So, we could get an exact number (power of two) values into the "Latency" box. Not any more.
In some paper I read about Jack setup, and it told about the best values always were power of two numbers. To far away of the present value 5.33 msec.
Is there a way  to fix and/or work around it???
